# Connecting to a Libre Base database in Monodevelop

Tags: c#, database, monodevelop, libreoffice-base

i have a librebase Database file ,  and i want to connect it to my monodevelop project.
İ cant find which plugins i need to install or which libraries i should be using .

Comment: Possibly via [JDBC](http://digiassn.blogspot.com/2006/07/java-creating-jdbc-connection-to.html)?

Comment: @MadMyche oh , it's looking like a solution , will try and give feedback thanks !